# Read stream from Facebook Live Videos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, streaming, live-streaming, facebook-live-api

I would like create a server to create subtitles for live videos on Facebook. I use Google Speech to convert sound to text. However, in order to do that, I need to read the facebook live streams.

Using Facebook Live API, with `me/live_videos`, I get the following response:

```
{
      "status": "LIVE",
      "stream_url": "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/{id}",
      "secure_stream_url": "rtmps://rtmp-api.facebook.com:443/rtmp/{id},
      "embed_html": "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id={video_id}\" width=\"400\" height=\"400\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",
      "id": "{id}"
    },
```

How can I read the streams from the above links?

Comment: What API are you using to add live subtitles?

Comment: @pexea12 Try my answer. You can definitely read the stream using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that there is no way to get the current stream from Facebook now. Maybe they should add this feature to their API.

Comment: Hello, so you're saying you can't use "secure_stream_url" to watch the live videos ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stream of ongoing live which you can play using any Dash Player.
To get the stream URL of Live Video, follow these steps:

1. Use the **LIVE_ID of video** (not Video_ID) to make the request.
2. Send a get request at this end point /LIVE_ID with fields as 'access_token' and 'dash_preview_url'.
3. This will return the URL of the ongoing live stream which can be played using any DASH Player.

You can refer to official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts#preview) for more information.

Comment: If the live is initiated in Facebook platform (GUI), not through API, do you know how can one obtain the live_video_id ?

Comment: @Sira No. There is no method to get Live ID from Video ID. This end point is for the purpose of viewing preview. Using GUI of Facebook to make live, you can directly view preview on the same web page. I think that is why Facebook has not added support for it yet.

Comment: It's important to note that the dash_preview_url can only be used for 4 hours and is limited to no more than 10 viewers.